# wGet using sed output in POST request

Tags: bash, sed, solaris, wget

Fairly new to the world of UNIX and trying to get my head round its quirks.

I am trying to make a fairly simple shell script that uses wGet to send a XML file that has been pre-processed with Sed .

I thought about using a pipe but it caused some weird behaviour where it just outputted my XML into the console.

This is what I have so far:

```
File_Name=$1
echo "File name being sent to KCIM is : " $1
wget "http://testserver.com" --post-file `sed s/XXXX/$File_Name/ < template.xml` |
 --header="Content-Type:text/xml"
```

From the output I can see I am not doing this right as its creating a badly formatted HTTP request

> POST data file `<?xml' missing: No such file or directory
>   Resolving <... failed: node name or service name not known.
>   wget: unable to resolve host address`<'

Bonus points for explaining what the problem is as well as solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `wget` the option `post-file` sends the contents of the named file. In your case you seem to be passing directly the data so you probably want `--post-data`.

The way you are doing it right now, `bash` gets the output from `sed` and `wget` gets something like:

```
wget ... --post-file <?xml stuff stuff stuff
```

So `wget` goes looking for a file called `<?xml` instead of using that text verbatim.